# ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Error when using equality in If Condition

Tags: python, numpy

I am taking this error in if condition of equality.
I tried steps in the similar questions but still I am taking the same error.

My script is as follows and I am using Jupyter Notebook:

```
  import numpy as np
  import math
  f1=np.array([-59,-28])
  f3=np.array([-39,76,94])
  f2=np.array([75])
  a=0
  b=0
  c=0
  x = np.array([1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 2]) # x coordinates in space
  y = np.array([-59, -59, -39, -39, -39, 75]) # f(x)
        def getNDDCoeffs(x, y):
        n = np.shape(y)[0]
        pyramid = np.zeros([n, n]) # Create a square matrix to hold pyramid
        pyramid[::,0] = y # first column is y
        for j in range(1,n):
            for i in range(n-j):
                # create pyramid by updating other columns
                if np.logical_and(x[i+j]==x[i],x[i]==f1):
                    a=a+1
                    pyramid[i][j] = f1[a-1]/math.factorial(a)
                elif np.logical_and(x[i+j]==x[i],x[i]==f3):
                    b=b+1
                    pyramid[i][j] = f3[a-1]/math.factorial(b)
                elif np.logical_and(x[i+j]==x[i],x[i]==f2):
                    c=c+1
                    pyramid[i][j] = f2[a-1]/math.factorial(c)
                else:
                    pyramid[i][j] = (pyramid[i+1][j-1] - pyramid[i][j-1]) / (x[i+j] - x[i])
        return pyramid[0] # return first row
  coeff_vector = getNDDCoeffs(x, y)
  print(coeff_vector)
```

In the script, I am trying to implement Hermite Interpolation in the form of the pyramid resolution of Newton's Divided Difference Method. f1[0] means the initial value, f1[1] is first derivative value and f1[2] is the second derivative. The same is valid for f2 and f3 arrays.

What could be the problem? If you can help me, I am soo glad.
Have a nice day!

Comment: it looks like `f1` that you're comparing against integers is equal to `np.array([-59,-28])`
so basically you're trying to compare `1` and '`[-59,-28]` which results in ValueError (same for f2 and f3)

Comment: Ahh, it was a very stupid mistake. I realized the problem. Thanks for helping.